# VSCode semicolon automatically added on save

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using VSCode and am writing a simple line of code that swaps the values of two variables.

```
[priceMin, priceMax] = [priceMax, priceMin]
```

On save, it adds a semicolon to the start of the line

```
;[priceMin, priceMax] = [priceMax, priceMin]
```

I currently have ESLint and Prettier extensions installed. Is this related to those extensions?

Comment: Yes it is. You should define a .prettierrc file in order to fix this problem. LEt me know if you need help on that (https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. In my case VS Code adds a semi-colon at the end.

Solution: Open Settings, search "Format On Save", change the option from Modification to file.

Comment: My team enabled format on save in the shared project settings at `.vscode/settings.json` and this started happening to me as well. Worse, the `;` sometimes got inserted in places that were invalid, breaking my TypeScript build.

Changing the "Editor: Format On Save Mode" setting my my personal settings to "File" (from "Modifications") was the only way I found to fix this also.